# complex text replace from the command line

Tags: regex, command-line, sed

A simplified example of what I want to do:

I have a file: input.txt which looks like

```
a 2 4 b
a 3 8 b
c 9 4 d
a 3 4 8 b
```

and a script: add.sh which takes command-line parameters and returns their sum

I want to search input.txt for all instances of the pattern `'a (.*) b'` where I pass the (.*) part as a command line parameter to add.sh.

For example, I want to do something like `sed 's/a \(.*\) b/a {add.sh \1} b/g' input.txt`
(that of course doesn't work).
So the output should look like

```
a 6 b
a 11 b
c 9 4 d
a 15 b
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/a (.*) b/"a ".`add.sh $1`." b"/eg' input.txt
```

Just make sure that add.sh doesn't output a newline.

Answer (score 0):

> And if perl isn't an option, you could
>   script it something like this:
>
> ```
> grep -e '^a .* b$' input.txt | sed -e 's/a \(.*\) b/\1/g' | while read LINE; do ./add.sh $LINE; done
> ```

I realized the above doesn't solve your problem, I just focused on your sed expression.

However, if you are keen on solving this problem using another shell script, it would probably look something like this:

```
cat input.txt | while read LINE; do
    if [[ "$LINE" =~ ^a (.*) b$ ]]; then
        echo -n "a "
        add.sh ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        echo " b"
    else
        echo $LINE
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If `add.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
arg1=$1
nums=$2
shift 2
for i in $nums
do
    sum=$((sum+i))
done
echo "$arg1 $sum $@"
```

then you could do:

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]* \)\(.*\)\( [^ ]*\)$/\1\"\2\"\3/' input.txt | xargs -L 1 ./add.sh
```

which would add the numbers on every line. To add them only for lines that start with "a" and end with "b" use this:

```
sed 's/^a \(.*\) b$/a \"\1\" b/' input.txt | xargs -L 1 ./add.sh
```

The "c 9 4 d" line is still processed by `add.sh` but the `sed` command doesn't add any quotes, so the script sees only "9" as `$2` and so the sum is only done once with the result as "9". The "4" is seen as part of the remainder of `$@`.